# php page redirect after operation

Tags: php, javascript

I have a page (index.php) which has a php grid with subpages(<<1,2,3,4>>). An operation on any page takes you back to index.php. Using $_GET['prd_p'] or $_REQUEST['prd_p'] gives you the page number. I want users to stay on a page after an operation, that means i have to use redirects.

```
<form name="frmSearchMe" action="<?php echo $page_name; ?>" method="POST">
<tr>
 <input class='form_button' type='submit' name='btnSubmit' value=' Save ' onclick='return checkerrors();' /></td>
 </tr>
//php codes here
</form>
```

Comment: sorry i did not complete my statement. but the question seemed answered. I'm trying out the solutions now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You have to redirect back to the same page after performing the operation.

```
header("location:url&".$_GET['prd_p']);
die();
```

You should use `die()` or `exit()` after the redirect statment.

Comment: maybe adding a cast (int) before the $_GET['prd_p'] could prevent some nice XSS...

Answer (score 1):

The location header can be used to redirect people

```
header('Location: index.php?stuff=squirrel');
```

If you're going to be setting values in there based on user data, make sure you validate them first (with a function like ctype_digit for example)

Comment: as per Shakti's answer, an exit() after the redirect is indeed called for. Without this PHP code execution will continue.